# How to Populate a DHIS2 dataset using DHIS2 Web API + R

Tags: r, dhis-2

I am an R user who wants to learn how to populate a DHIS2 hosted dataset via the DHIS2 Web API. Specifically, I would like to test the concept using the DHIS2 Demo server (https://play.dhis2.org/2.38nightly/dhis-web-dataentry/index.action) , by populating the data entry form for Rosinor CHP (**Sierra Leone -> Kamba -> Samu -> Rosinor CHP**), dataset: **HIV Pediatric Monthly Summary**, Period: **March 2023** as shown below.

I would like to achieve this using R, however I have yet found detailed documentation to assist, could I be pointed in the right direction? The main difficulty I am having is identifying the data entry form in R and then populating specific fields in the data entry form.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're trying to screen scrape data from this site. Please see: https://rvest.tidyverse.org/ for some introductory info on screen scraping in R. Sites that leverage javascript to generate content may require you to use something more flexible like Selenium, if this is the case you may wish to check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html

Comment: No, I do not wish to screen scrape, I wish to do CRUD operations via the DHIS2 API

Answer (score 0):

Tumaini.

Check out this [DHIS2 community thread](https://community.dhis2.org/t/send-data-to-dhis2-instance-from-r/52665) for more insights